# WinAPI: InternetCloseHandle function closes the handle but not the connection

Tags: windows, winapi, network-programming, msdn

I call [wininet\InternetOpenUrlA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then wininet\InternetReadFile and when I'm done I call [wininet\InternetCloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which returns True. That means that the handle successfully closed, but the connection is still in established state.

Why doesn't the connection close when I call wininet\InternetCloseHandle ?

Answer (score 4):

WinInet can cache and reuse connections for future requests to the same server.

Comment: Well, I need that connection closed before the next request, because a new route table entry is created and the request should go through a different interface, but because the connection doesn't close the request goes through the old interface and ignores the route table entry.

Comment: As a temporary workaround each request is managed in a process, and when is done I kill the process which forces the connection to close.

Comment: When calling `InternetOpenUrl()`, omit the `INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT` flag so it does not use a cached connection, and omit the `INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION` flag so it does not cache the connection. Another option is to use `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` to manually add a "Connection: close" header to your requests, so it forces the server to close the connection after each response.

Answer (score 4):

WinInet tries to re-use sockets where it can, so even when you release the handle it can choose to keep the socket active, ready for the next call to InternetOpen. Most of the time this is a good thing and you don't need to worry about it.

If you **really** need it to be closed immediately, you can fool WinInet into doing this by calling InternetSetOption after your final InternetCloseHandle:

```
...
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0);
```

Doing this tells WinInet that global WinInet settings have changed (e.g. in the Registry) so it has no choice but to close all sockets and reset itself. However this obviously is not the intended usage and will have some performance impact if you are making lots of connections with WinInet.