# WinInet InternetCloseHandle does not close the connection

Tags: delphi, wininet

I use this code to get some data from a URL:

```
function GetUrlContent(const Url: string): string;
var
  NetHandle: HINTERNET;
  UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1024] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
  Size: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  NetHandle := InternetOpen('App', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if not Assigned(NetHandle) then Exit;
  try
    UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    if not Assigned(UrlHandle) then  Exit;
    try
      { Proceed with download }
      Size := 0;
      repeat
        if not InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead) then Break;
        if BytesRead = 0 then Break;
        SetLength(Result, Size + BytesRead);
        Move(Buffer, Result[Size + 1], BytesRead);
        Inc(Size, BytesRead);
      until False;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(NetHandle);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that it seems like the connection is still established after I get the data, like if `InternetCloseHandle()` crashs or is buggy.

I want to close the active connection of the function after the result is returned.

Comment: Try some debugging where in your code does the failure occur?

Comment: Is it possible to trim the code down into a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: WinInet caches connections internally for later reuse. This is documented behavior: "*The WinINet API caches a single connection handle for each HINTERNET handle generated by InternetOpen.*" On a side note, `HINTERNET` is not a pointer, you should not be using `Assigned()` to test it. Use `if NetHandle = 0 then Exit ;` instead of `if not Assigned(NetHandle) then Exit;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinAPI: InternetCloseHandle function closes the handle but not the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972915/). Try using `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` to manually add a "Connection: close" header to your request so it asks the server to close the connection after sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all problem resolved

```
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0);
```

I got answer heer thanks a lot
[WinAPI: InternetCloseHandle function closes the handle but not the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972915/)